# Angularfire access object key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How can I print out the key of an object returned from Firebase?
Specifically, how do I print out the team names? eg. "Awesome Team"

Controller:

```
app.controller('TeamsController', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject','ENV', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, ENV){

        var app_id = ENV.FIREBASE_APP_ID;
        var ref = new Firebase("https://"+app_id+".firebaseio.com/teams");
        $scope.teams = $firebaseObject(ref);

    }
]);
```

The data returned is:

```
{"$id":"teams","$priority":null,"Awesome Team":{"created":"11-11-1111","size":3},"Team 1":{"created":"26-11-1111","size":4}}
```

Then in the view:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
        <td>{{$id}}</td>
        <td>{{team.created}}</td>
        <td>{{team.size}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="">X</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Perhaps restructure your data? Teams seem like it should be a list, so perhaps treat your teams with a unique id and store the team name as a key inside each team id, then you may use the `$firebaseArray`. If you are supposed to save all your teams using a `$firebaseObject` it will require more data to be treated than needed.
A few helpful articles to structure your data can be found [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a Firebase reference with ng-repeat should be done with `$firebaseArray` instead of `$firebaseObject`. When using `$firebaseArray`, each child has an `$id` property containing the object's key.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-meta-fields

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
    <td>{{team.$id}}</td>
    <td>{{team.created}}</td>
    <td>{{team.size}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="">X</button></td>
</tr>
```